# How to adjust components position in a line

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, jcomponent

How can I align components in a line with a table without affecting a gap between components of a 5px?
I had an idea to set value for hgap of FlowLayout to zero, but if I do it will change a gap also between components...
Here is the screenshot and code, if I wasn't clear:

How I want:
[image: HOW I WANT]

How it is:
[image: HOW IT IS]

Code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Test3 {

    private JButton addNewColumnButton;
    private JButton calculateColumnButton;
    private JButton resultButton;
    private JLabel textLabel;
    private JTextField columnField;
    private JTextField resultField;
    private JComboBox columnListCB;
    private JTable table;
    private String[] tableCols = {
        "First Column", "Second Column", "Third Column", "", "", "", ""
    };
    private Object[][] tableRows = {
        {true, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {true, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {true, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {true, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {true, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {true, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {true, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {true, null, null, null, null, null, null, null}
    };

    public Test3() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test2");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(getPanelComponents());
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel getPanelComponents() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

        JPanel center = new JPanel(new GridLayout());
        table = new JTable(tableRows, tableCols);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(450, 128));
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        center.add(new JScrollPane(table));

        JPanel eastPanel = new JPanel();
        Box eastPanelBox = Box.createVerticalBox();
        addNewColumnButton = new JButton("Add New Column");
        addNewColumnButton.setAlignmentX(Box.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        eastPanelBox.add(addNewColumnButton);
        eastPanelBox.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(35));
        columnField = new JTextField();
        columnField.setAlignmentX(Box.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        eastPanelBox.add(columnField);
        eastPanelBox.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(5));
        columnListCB = new JComboBox(tableCols);
        columnListCB.setAlignmentX(Box.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        eastPanelBox.add(columnListCB);
        eastPanelBox.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(5));
        calculateColumnButton = new JButton("Calculate Column");
        calculateColumnButton.setAlignmentX(Box.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        eastPanelBox.add(calculateColumnButton);
        eastPanel.add(eastPanelBox);

        JPanel southPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 5, 5));

        resultButton = new JButton("Calculate");
        southPanel.add(resultButton);
        textLabel = new JLabel("Result:");
        southPanel.add(textLabel);
        resultField = new JTextField(10);
        southPanel.add(resultField);

        panel.add(center, BorderLayout.WEST);
        panel.add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        panel.add(eastPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        return panel;   
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test3();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: see `JPanel southPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 0, 0));` this is (`5pixels is default` gap) sets by `new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 5, 5));` FlowLayout could not be proper for this job, you can to help you by using Borders `xxx.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));`

Comment: So should I then create two panels for this properties? Like,  `code JPanel panel = new JPanel(); panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(null, 0));` and then inner JPanel which holds FlowLayout and his components with gap of 5px ? p.s. I actually don't like that if you set a null for a color parameter they will anyway init a default color :/

Comment: Any other solution to this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @mKorbel comments, the five pixel vertical space is added by the default layout of `JPanel`, [`FlowLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FlowLayout.html). The image below shows `vgap` set to zero.

```
JPanel eastPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 0));
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that works. Now I understand. But how I'm going to fix for south panel ? Should I do exactly same as for east panel, I mean instead of Flowlayout, Box southPanelBox = Box.createHorizontalBox();? i would really like to keep FlowLayout if possible :)

Comment: Ah, I missed that in your images; it looks like you could change the `hgap` to zero in the `SOUTH`.

Comment: Yea man, that works, but as I said before, it will pull and components back, which is not my result, I need to keep a 5px space between them . Do you have any ideas left, or you think it's just best to use the same layout "Box" like with eastPanel ?

Comment: `Box` would be a good a alternative, and the "Result:" field will expand nicely, too. If you want to manage everything in a single layout, try `GridBagLayout`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14755487/230513).

Comment: Yea that's how I did, box is fine.. However, GridBagLayout I don't want to challenge yet, probably in a next project.