# How to make this GUI layout in Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, gridbaglayout

For a project I have an almost working code, but I do not have the GUI. I want to make a screen that consists of clickable labels and has the following design:

[image]

I was thinking about first making the middle `GridBagLayout` with with a dimension of 6 by 2. Then 'wrapping' that up and adding the two buttons to the side, and then 'wrapping' that and adding the two buttons below.

I am inexperienced with Swing, and I have no idea how to start. I hope someone can give me some hints in the right direction.

Comment: I can highly recommend you download Eclipse and then you add [THIS](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/wbpro/?hl=de-DE). I think that'll get you on the right track pretty fast.

Comment: The design you want is your profile picture..? You need to tell us more..... :D

Comment: @MarounMaroun: It's to make absolutely sure everybody knows what he wants.

Comment: :-) I'm very serious about it yes. Besides that I cannot post pictures yet (although this imgur link kind of shows?) because I do not have enough reputation. Unfortunately I cannot upvote you guys either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several approaches to a very similar layout using `GridBagLayout` and/or nesting are shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14755487/230513). Consider using `JButton` for each clickable area, rather than `JLabel`. If you go with a nested layout,

- Use `BorderLayout` for the enclosing panel.
- Add buttons to `EAST` and `WEST` for the leftmost and rightmost areas.
- Add a `GridLayout(1, 2)` of buttons to `SOUTH` for the bottom row.
- Add a `GridLayout(2, 6)` of buttons to `CENTER` for the central twelve areas.

Addendum: A critical issue will be what you want the resize behavior to be.

Comment: I am very happy with this! I copy-pasted an example from your link and edited it to my own needs. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

as said in the comments above you could (should ?) use the WYSIWYG Window Builder plugin available for Eclipse; it's simple to use.

However, that doesn't answer your question, so to do so, here is how I would structure the UI if I were to make one like that :
http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=902716gZHkK26.jpg

I basically use BoxLayout because that's the one I'm most familiar with. Every Rectangle is a JPanel. I think the image is pretty self eplanatory.

Comment: Thank you! I used the approach above though because it creates cleaner code. Thanks for your effort it is appreciated.