# Make a component span multiple cells in GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I'm building a simple app that I can use to put some  questions and their answers in it and saves them to diffrent array lists for later use(Kind of like one of those Quiz Cards that has the question on one side and the answer on the other) while I was building my UI I reached a brick wall that i can't seem to get pass.

in the following code I would like the "next" button to span multiple columns and be wider than the text areas

[image]

but when ever I try to set the widthx variable to multiple columns nothing seems to happen, can some one explain why is this happening and possibly how to fix it?
thanks

```
    public class FillingCards extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    JTextArea question;
    JTextArea answer;
    JButton button;
    ArrayList<String> questions;
    ArrayList<String> answers;
    GridBagConstraints gbc;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FillingCards card = new FillingCards();
        card.setupGUI();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, card);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

    }

    public FillingCards() {
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        question = new JTextArea(5, 5);
        answer = new JTextArea(5, 5);
        button = new JButton("next");

    }

    public void setupGUI() {

        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        JScrollPane qs = new JScrollPane(question);
        qs.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        qs.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        qs.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        this.add(qs, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        this.add(new JLabel("Answer: "), gbc);
        JScrollPane as = new JScrollPane(answer);
        as.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        as.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        this.add(as, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        this.add(button, gbc);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        questions = new ArrayList<>();
        answers = new ArrayList<>();
        question.setLineWrap(true);
        answer.setLineWrap(true);

    }

    public void startFilling() {
        questions.add(question.getText());
        answers.add(answer.getText());

        question.setText(null);
        answer.setText(null);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        startFilling();

    }

}
```

Comment: GBC are columns based

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14755487/230513).

Answer (score 0):

OK, you have accidentally run into a quirk. While the layout looks easy, it
took me also some time to get my head around this. 
(By the way, stretching a button horizontally is not an optimal UI desing.)

The reason is the way managers are built. If the layout does not contain at 
least two components in a row, it is not possible to span a component. 
Your layout consists only of one column, therefore, setting `widthx` > 1 does
not work. There are two ways how to cope with this: we can either place some
dummy components into the layout, or we can put some space before and after
the areas to decrease their widths.

I provide three solutions: a) GridBagLayout with dummy labels, b) GridBagLayout
with insets and c) MigLayout with gaps.

[image: Quiz cards]

**Solution 1**

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class FillingCards extends JPanel {

    private JTextArea question;
    private JTextArea answer;
    private JButton button;
    private JLabel label;


    public FillingCards() {


        setupGUI();
    }

    private void setupGUI() {

        question = new JTextArea(12, 22);
        answer = new JTextArea(12, 22);
        button = new JButton("Next");
        label = new JLabel("Answer");   

        question.setBorder(
                BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder()
        );

        answer.setBorder(
                BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder()
        );        

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints  gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 10, 5, 10);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        add(question, gbc);

        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 0;
        add(label, gbc);

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        add(answer, gbc);

        gbc.gridwidth = 3;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 0;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        add(button, gbc);

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 0;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        add(new JLabel("  "), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        add(new JLabel("  "), gbc);  

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Quiz cards");
        FillingCards card = new FillingCards();
        frame.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, card);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }    
}
```

Two labels are placed in the first and the third cell, beneath the Next button.
This is not a clean solution and was created mainly to demonstrate the issue.

```
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
gbc.gridwidth = 1;
gbc.weighty = 0;
gbc.weightx = 0;
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 3;
add(new JLabel("  "), gbc);

gbc.gridx = 2;
gbc.gridy = 3;
add(new JLabel("  "), gbc);
```

Two dummy labels are created. The width of these labels determines
the width of the left and right gaps.

**Solution 2**

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class FillingCards2 extends JPanel {

    private JTextArea question;
    private JTextArea answer;
    private JButton button;
    private JLabel label;


    public FillingCards2() {


        setupGUI();
    }

    private void setupGUI() {

        question = new JTextArea(12, 22);
        answer = new JTextArea(12, 22);
        button = new JButton("Next");
        label = new JLabel("Answer");   

        question.setBorder(
                BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder()
        );

        answer.setBorder(
                BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder()
        );        

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints  gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 15, 5, 15);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        add(question, gbc);

        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 0;
        add(label, gbc);

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        add(answer, gbc);

        gbc.insets.left = 5;
        gbc.insets.right = 5;
        gbc.gridwidth = 3;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 0;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        add(button, gbc);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Quiz cards");
        FillingCards2 card = new FillingCards2();
        frame.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, card);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }    
}
```

In this example, we use the `insets` attribute to create the desired
layout. The left and right insets of the label and the text areas are wider
that those of the button.

```
gbc.insets.left = 5;
gbc.insets.right = 5;
gbc.gridwidth = 3;
gbc.weightx = 1;
gbc.weighty = 0;
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 3;
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
add(button, gbc);
```

The left and right insets are changed from 15px to 5px. This way we achieve
that the button is wider than the other components.

**Solution 3**

The third solution was created with a `MigLayout` manager. We need less
code to create the layout.

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;


public class MigLayoutFillingCards extends JFrame {

    public MigLayoutFillingCards() {

        initUI();

        setTitle("Quiz cards");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }


    private void initUI() {

        setLayout(new MigLayout("wrap"));

        JTextArea area1 = new JTextArea();
        JTextArea area2 = new JTextArea();

        area1.setBorder(
                BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder()
        );

        area2.setBorder(
                BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder()
        );                

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Answer");
        JButton btn = new JButton("Next");

        add(area1, "w 250, h 150, grow, push, gap 15 15 0 0");
        add(label, "gap 15 15 0 0");
        add(area2, "w 250, h 150, grow, push, gap 15 15 0 0");
        add(btn, "growx, pushx");

        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MigLayoutFillingCards ex = new MigLayoutFillingCards();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The desired layout was created with a `gap` constraint, which adds additional
space to the sides of a component.

Answer (score 0):

And the short answer is - gbc.gridwidth is the parameter that allows a component to span more than one column. For example, if you have 3 columns and 4 rows and you want a label to occupy the complete top row, then you need to assign the first cell for the label. and set gbc.gridwidth = 3;